# Cypress browser state maintains log in. How do I stop this from occurring?

Tags: typescript, testing, integration-testing, cypress

I have written a number of cypress e2e tests for an app that requires logging in. I have written successful tests, however the tests have started to fail. The tests expect the app to be logged out when they start otherwise they fail when trying to find the email and password fields. When cypress opens its browser window the app is logged in. Earlier I would merely logout through the cypress browser and rerun the test. Now it will open again as if it is still logged in.

How can I prevent the cypress browser window from starting with the page logged in already? Is there a way to refresh the app state so that it forgets about any previous log ins?

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache and if you've have any cookies. try to clear them too and then re-run the tests

Comment: I have put cy.clearLocalStorage() and cy.clearCookies() in both the beforeEach functions and in the start of individual tests. Should this be enough to affect the desired change?

Answer (score 5):

try to also clean `indexedDB`:

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase('firebaseLocalStorageDb');
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I was having the same issue with Cypress when paired with Firebase/Firestore. After some digging, I see that Auth persistence can be configured. See this article:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: but I do not want to change how auth state is persisted because of a test. How can we enforce clearing the auth state before the test?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress clears all [cookies](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearcookies.html) and [local storage](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clearlocalstorage.html) before each test. This suggests that your problem is one of the following:

a) You are running multiple logical tests within a single test, or

b) The system under test uses another mechanism to persist the login

If you aren't doing *a)* then you need to find out what is stored (and where) when a user logs in. Once you know this, you can write a mechanism to clear it out.

## Additional Cypress Notes

One of the core concepts in Cypress is that you should avoid conditional testing. For example, in other frameworks it is common to run the equivalent of...

```
// Not real code
if (getelement(x).exists) {

}
```

But that's not the Cypress way.

The correct way to handle your specific case is to choose one of the following.

1. Navigate to a URL that will always allow your test to sign in, such as `http://www.example.com/login/` - where even logged in users can submit the sign in form
2. Use a query parameter to signal to the server that it should clear any user state (if it is not stored in one of the expected placed - imagine a server that pins the IP address against some state, etc)
3. Embed data in the DOM, in a way that means it will always be found by Cypress... for example: `<body data-logged-in="true">`. You can then read this attribute in your test as it is always there...

Obtaining the attribute:

```
cy.get('body').should('have.attr', 'data-logged-in').then((loggedIn) => {
    // Use loggedIn here...
});
```

Comment: I have eliminated (a). In the case of (b) I have tried logging out at the beginning of a test. This merely inverts the problem. Instead the tests often fail because they cannot find the logout button. The problem occurs when I have previously logged out and when I restart the tests, it is logged in already.

Comment: @radiobrain77 additional information added. Have you determined where your page stores this login information? It must be kept somewhere other than cookies or local storage?